# Please explain why this simple circuit is latching 'on', but only when a fan is attached

Tags: transistors, infrared

My son and I made a circuit using an electronics kit.  It's supposed to work so that when the IR receiver receives a signal from a remote control, it turns on the motor.

It does that, but I noticed that if you hold the remote control button long enough for the motor to reach top speed, then the circuit latches and the motor continues  to spin even after you release the remote's button.

It only does this if the green fan is attached to the motor, otherwise the motor stops when you release the remote's button.

My first thought was something environmental, like heat from the motor (though I doubt that), light from outside - but it happens even if the IR is covered.

So is it something about the load on the motor affecting the transistor?

I'm a novice at electronics.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foLP3v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you read the part number from the infra-red receiver U24?

Comment: @transistor The only identifing mark is "LFN" - thanks.

Comment: @OlinLathrop A bit over-the-top here.

Comment: Is there a certain rep required to berate newcomers (who may be young kids) and communicate in what many would consider obnoxious manner without repercussions?

Comment: Two possible things to try:

Comment: Something to try: put C1 between base and emitter instead of base to collector; you want to filter the base voltage with respect to the emitter (positive side of the cap to V+).  The IR receiver's high output is only guaranteed to be Vcc - 0.5; 0.5 volts is very close to turning on the PNP transistor, so you may also want to try putting a pull-up on the base to emitter leg.

Comment: Not an answer, but where did you get this circuit? The placement of C1 is weird, a more logical place would be to connect the + side to the LFN out pin (and R1).

Comment: @W5VO: This is the EE site.  EEs communicate circuits with schematics.  We have a right to insist on that.  I suppose I could have silently voted to close, but that wouldn't have left the OP with a path to fix things.

Comment: @transistor: Asking about a circuit without posting a schematic is obnoxious.

Comment: It was not the OP's _intent_ to be obnoxious. However ...

Comment: @transistor: Irrelevant.  The OP basically said *"I'm new here, but I'm not going to bother learning your conventions and this site before barging in and asking a question.  I have no respect for your accumulated experience and expertise in this field."*.

Comment: As far as I can see the OP met all the requirements of the Help Center and for a first-time post was reasonably good. Your response was in breach of the [behaviour guidelines](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) "_Be welcoming and patient, especially with those who may not know everything you do._" If schematics are a requirement then that needs to be added to the rules or put in the site tagline. It took me quite a few posts to figure out how things work on the site.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Your vocal comments are not helping the OP "fix" his post, they just come across as noob bashing and ego building. On top of that, you're complaining about something that's already better than a Fritzing diagram. Not to diminish their importance, but schematics are hardly a requirement for questions on this site.

Comment: @transistor. I think the answers provided can help the OP get the circuit working dependably. That would not be the first OP who voiced their opinion. Some have been much more rude than this OP. I just ignored it. Solve the problem, go to another one.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I do have respect for everybody's experience and expertise, and I did post a photo of the circuit, so you could easily see what the circuit was.  I didn't and don't see the difference between that and a schematic, and all I did was ask you what the difference is.  If you weren't so autocratic and supercilious in your comments I would have been much more likely to create the schematic without hesitation regardless, but your bossy tone and the fact that I still don't see how the photo doesn't qualify as a schematic, made me ask what the difference is.  Thank you for all answers.

Comment: @Jim: Circuits are communicated with schematics.  That's how it's done.  It's not relevant whether you understand why or not for the purpose of this question.  If that's what you want to know, ask it separately.  Comments here aren't the right place to answer that.  No, I couldn't easily see the circuit from the photo.  I'm not going to waste time deciphering a photo or wiring diagram to get the information a schematic would tell me outright.  Once a real schematic was posted, the answer was obvious in a few seconds.

Comment: @transistor spent years fighting that fight. Apparently some people are untouchable regardless of how rude they are.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foLP3v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Your circuit.*

A search for LFN shows up the [PIC-1018SCL](http://www.ozitronics.com/data/pic1018scl.pdf) via [this site](https://twinschip.com/Infrared). It's an infra-red receiver with built-in logic to pull its output low when IR is received.

In normal operation it will draw current from the base of Q1 via R1 when an IR signal is received. This will pass current to the motor and start it up. If all is well removing the IR source will result in the transistor switching off and the motor slowing to a stop.

The fact that it keeps going is a slight mystery as the LFN should be either fully off or on.

One possibility is that C1 is leaking a little current. If so, this will turn on the Q1 a little but not enough to supply the stall current and start up the motor.

If, however, LFN pulls low, Q1 turns fully on and the motor spins up to speed, the current caused by leakage may be enough to keep the motor running.

Try removing C1 and see if you get the same effect.

Comment: Thanks, I pulled C1 and the motor was pulsing, presumably because the IR signal is pulsed from the remote, so that may affect what the effect you described.  I really need a constant IR source... Your question about the IR-REC made me wonder if it was malfunctioning because it's source voltage was too low...

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? The pulsed signal from the IR should be very fast - much faster than the motor can react.

Comment: I do - I'll investigate after work today.

Comment: I recommend you un-accept my answer until you reckon it's correct. Accepting it may dissuade other better answers.

Comment: I agree with this answer in that I can't see any 'normal' reason why this circuit would latch: there is no (positive) feedback. Weird possibilities could include the suggested 'latching' behaviour in the motor itself, or something related to temperature (airflow) or ambient IR light (modulated by the fan blades).

Comment: Thanks for all your help and ideas everybody.  I rebuilt the circuit, but couldn't get the same behaviour, it just worked as you would expect.  I tried different combinations of batteries in case that was the cause.  So that's disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this circuit needs a pull-up resistor of about 2.2k 1/4 watt from the base to the emitter of Q1. This is from the spec sheet for this part:
Voh = Vcc-0.5 Volts.
Vol = 0.2 to 0.4 volts max
Even though the output is not OC type, the LFN out rail is low enough to induce a trickle current in Q1, so it may NOT shut off even if LFN out = high. A pull-up resistor is needed or the state of Q1 can be unpredictable.

Comment: @transistor. I do think that a pull-up resistor is important, or use a PNP darlington, based on the spec sheet for Voh. This should be passed along to the OP, whether I get any votes or not.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason when I rebuilt the circuit the problem didn't reoccur, so I can't confirm your advice fixes this one.

Comment: @JimW. That is why I used the word "unpredictable". If Q1 becomes warm or hot, it is naturally more 'leaky'. In a cold test lab it will be less leaky. If the motor behavior becomes unpredictable again, you still have another trick to use. My advice was based on the LPN spec sheets, not my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because the battery voltage collapses when the motor is loaded.  That runs the IR receiver out of spec, and it pulls its output low regardless of what it is receiving.  That keeps the fan on, which keeps the power voltage low, etc.  This is just a guess on my part from looking at the schmatic and the symptoms, but it seems quite plausible.

There are two ways to verify this.  First, put a meter on the power voltage.  If I'm right, you will see significantly more sag when the motor is loaded (had the propeller on it) than when unloaded.  A scope would be better since maybe there are short low-going spikes.  One obvious problem with the circuit is a lack of capacitance across the supply.

Second, use a separate battery to power the IR receiver and the motor.  If the problem is as I described, then this should work even when the battery running the motor drops in voltage.

A datasheet for the IR receiver would be useful, of course.